# neo4j causal clustering, can't form with ec2 instances

Tags: neo4j

Did anyone successfully setup a `Neo4j causal cluster`?

I'm unable to setup one with 3 `ec2 t2.micro` instances... all Neo4j servers running but not yet formed cluster (waited for ever).

Is there is any minimum requirement (`RAM`, etc) ?

This is the log im seeing in 1 of Neo4j server :

```
2017-07-18 03:35:51.303+0000 INFO  Attempting to connect to the other cluster members before continuing...
```

also getting below continuously 2017-07-20 17:55:01.963+0000 INFO [o.n.c.c.c.RaftMachine] Election started with vote request: Vote.Request from MemberId{3da30036} {term=250, candidate=MemberId{3da30036}, lastAppended=0, lastLogTerm=0} and members: [MemberId{9e1be61d}, MemberId{3da30036}]
2017-07-20 17:55:10.475+0000 INFO [o.n.c.c.c.m.MembershipWaiter] Leader commit unknown
2017-07-20 17:55:12.919+0000 INFO [o.n.c.c.c.RaftMachine] Election timeout triggered ... not sure why leader unable to elect.

Comment: Can you share with us the configuration and the files of the three nodes ?

Comment: # Network connector configuration
dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0
dbms.connectors.default_advertised_address=10.0.0.1
# Causal Clustering Configuration
dbms.mode=CORE
causal_clustering.initial_discovery_members=10.0.0.1:5000,10.0.0.2:5000,10.0.0.3:5000 this is basic config for all 3 files same except advertised address.

Comment: once i got below error Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.causalclustering.core.state.CoreLife@21fba6fd' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Failed to join a cluster with members {clusterId=null, bootstrappable=false, coreMembers={}}. Another member should have published a clusterId but none was detected. Please restart the cluster.".

Comment: i changed some configs and looks like cluster joined instances, but getting below exception and still unable to access neo4j with 7474. what could be the issue...any idea?

Comment: 2017-07-19 16:05:06.644+0000 ERROR [o.n.c.c.s.RaftMessageHandler] Failed to download snapshot StoreId mismatch and not empty

Comment: org.neo4j.causalclustering.catchup.storecopy.StoreCopyFailedException: StoreId mismatch and not empty at org.neo4j.causalclustering.core.state.snapshot.CoreStateDownloader.downloadSnapshot(CoreStateDownloader.java:89)  at org.neo4j.causalclustering.core.state.RaftMessageHandler.downloadSnapshot(RaftMessageHandler.java:117)  at org.neo4j.causalclustering.core.state.RaftMessageHandler.handle(RaftMessageHandler.java:72)  at org.neo4j.causalclustering.core.state.RaftMessageHandler.handle(RaftMessageHandler.java:36)  at org.neo4j.causalclustering.core.server.BatchingMessageHandler.run(Bat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally able to fix the issue and now my causal clustering is working fine. Basically each neo4j server neo4j.conf should use below property with proper IP number dbms.connectors.default_advertised_address=10.0.0.1 if creating under AWS with ec2 instances this should be private IP of instance and its started working, initially I used public IP of instance

Comment: do you have a sample config?